# Android how to create custom compass pointing to my home?

Tags: android, geolocation, compass-geolocation

hello everyone i am developing an application that makes a compass  pointing to my house
 i am so tired and i can't get any results from any book or forum 
i found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715057/how-to-make-compass-point-to-my-particular-latitude-longitude-location-based-on) question it's very good but i need something more advanced any ideas maybe from longitude latitude connected to the compass

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4316717/813951

Comment: dupe of stackoverflow.com/a/4316717/813951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you acheiveing this ? is it an image in the background of your home ?
because you can rotate the image in the background so compass will point to your home

Comment: no it's not image i need to make the compass needle to point on my house instead of the NORTH

Comment: actually i am doing this with the basic compass (witch using sensor manager)
i believe the answer will be inside onDraw(Canvas canvas) method

Comment: okay chack this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680268/pointing-to-a-specific-location-compass-using-an-image-instead-of-drwaing

Comment: thank you very very very much  it look just what i am looking for
i hope this code will be good

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Location Manager to get the longitude and latitude. More on this here: [How to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android)

Comment: actually i need to connect the compass with specific location to point on it like NORTH